# put <elem> values in xml into an array

Tags: python, django, xml, xquery

I have an xquery that returns this example of xml

```
<root>
   <elem> xd </elem>
   <elem> lol </elem>
   <elem> hihi </elem>
</root>
```

how do I put the values ​​of the element inside an array?
example: x = [xd,lol,hihi]
anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's built-in module `xml.etree.ElementTree` module for this. It will not directly convert the XML structure to the desired output but will provide a way to parse through given XML structure which we can further use to get to the output. Before proceeding, I must warn you that this module is [vulnerable to certain attacks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities), so if you are accepting untrusted or unauthenticated data, do it at your own risk.

Here's how you can proceed:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = """
<root>
   <elem> xd </elem>
   <elem> lol </elem>
   <elem> hihi </elem>
</root>
"""

# `ET.fromstring` reads an XML string and returns the root of the structure
root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

# Iterate through XML nodes and extract text
x = [node.text.strip() for node in root]

print(x)
```

#### Output

---

```
['xd', 'lol', 'hihi']
```

In the code, we first import the module. Then, using `fromstring()` method of `ElementTree`, we get the root of the XML structure. We then use this root and iterate through the nodes within this node and extract the text. The text might contain some whitespaces, so, we use the `strip()` method of the string to remove them.

The above method considers the XML data to be in string. If you want to read the data from a file you can either read the file's whole content as a string and pass it to `fromstring()` or you can directly pass the filename to the `parse()` method like so:

```
root = ET.parse("my_xml_file.xml")
```

Comment: but when passing to string, will not lose the query made before? 
I already have a variable that returns this xml (res1)

Comment: @TradePortugal Yes you can pass `res1` instead of `xml_string`. You basically need to pass any string that contains XML